# WebStorm and Winston logging issue

Tags: webstorm, winston

As soon as I use [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) I loose all the WebStorm console logs
ie:

```
winston.log('test') // this is never logged to the webstorm console
console.log('test') // this is logged to the webstorm console
```

Is there a way to have the Winston logs showing in the WebStorm console ?

Answer (score 2):

```
winston.log('test'); // doesn't works
```

but

```
winston.log('<log level>','test'); // works
```

Or

```
wiston.<log level ie:error, warn, info, verbose, debug, silly>('test');
```

my issue was, there is no "log" level, but there is a command "log" that expect a log level...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
var winston = require('winston');

console.log(' console test');
winston.log('info', 'Hello winston log!');
winston.info('Hello winston info!');

winston.level = 'debug';
winston.log('debug', 'Now my winston debug messages are written to console!');
```

[image]

If it doesn't work for you, you must have done something very special